# Flash Builder 4 - view output in the browser while step-by-step debugging?

Tags: actionscript-3, debugging, ide, flash-builder

As you know, the browser just hangs when I put a break point and running the project step-by-step and the app is viewable in browser only after I resume the execution.

I was just wondering if there is any way to see the changes in the browser as I run through step-by-step executing in the debugging mode.

If it is supported officially then is there any hack or work around?

I want to see the changes **visually**, please don't suggest any other debugging methods(like tracing and logging)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have found in all these days is this is not possible because the debugger attached to the browser will freeze the browser when we are debugging at the break-point.

However, I found a way to see the output in browser as it executes

All we need is to arrange browser and flash builder side-by-side or stacked so that both fb and browser are visible. Now, as you execute step-by-step you can see the visual changes in the browsers.

This will be much easier if you have a split screen (dual monitor)

Only caveat is that it does not show the tween animations which shouldn't be a problem in most of the cases (at least for me)

Hope this helps some one out there